# How to create a "Hello World" iPhone App with cordova 1.5 and xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I want to create an Hello World iPhone app using Cordova1.5 and xcode 4.2 I have installed latest version of phonegap(cordova1.5) in Xcode 4.2. How can I create a Helloworld app. Can anyone send me useful links for creating apps with cordova1.5 and xcode 4.2 ?

Comment: phonegap has nice tutorials, check their website

Comment: http://phonegap.com/start/ in this link there is "PhoneGap-based Application" in xcode but I've installed, there is "Cordova-based Application" in xcode. Is there any difference in folder structure or coding between older version and cordova1.5 version ?

Comment: I don't know, never worked with PhoneGap. But I suppose it's the same. Just give it a try

Comment: @jimca there is no difference in the process or the project structure. As long as the code is concern most of the high-level api remains same but you may find changes in the internal structure if you have applied any internal fixes to previous versions.

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2015/8/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PhoneGap has a lot of tutorial already available which you can check from here:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials

For simple helloworld though you can follow these steps:

- Open XCode and create a new project with "Cordova-based Application"
  template
- Give project name and Un-select the "Use Automatic Reference
  Counting"
- XCode will create a template project
- Run the application first time and it will generate the additional
  /www folder in the project directory
- Select the project and go to `File` -> `Add Files to "your project"` -> `Select /www
  folder from project directory and add as a reference in project`
- Re-run again and you should see the alert dialog saying "Cordova is
  working"

You can check the same tutorial with screenshot at [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4)

Comment: @ dhaval I am using xcode4.2 and cordova1.5, I've added www directory from "/Users/Shared/Cordova/Frameworks/Cordova.framework/www" to my project, but still get "Build Failed " error. Is it correct or where can I find www folder ?

Comment: build failed is compilation error, the error console will show the list of lines having issues. can you put them in your question

Comment: These are some part of the error message that I got. 
"main.m
'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable
'release' is unavailable
 ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
AppDelegate.m
 autorelease is unavailable
 ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'
 ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealoc'
"

Comment: yes these are because of the `Automatic Reference Counting`, you need to unselect it when you create new project, or you need to remove `relese` calls

Answer (score 4):

Just Follow this link [Phonegap Link](http://phonegap.com/start)

Recently `Phonegap` was renamed to `Cordova`. So if it is mentioned as Cordova Based Application ,then it means a phonegap based application.The wiki will be updated soon.

And here are some tutorials [site Links](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

First update the mac osx to 10.7.3, then download phonegap 1.5.0 is renamed as cordova, then try to create coredova app by following Template.